# Print trailing zeros in a QString

Tags: qt, string-formatting

I am using Qt and want to print a data value (double) in a label; however, the trailing zeros are lopped off.  I know in C I can use *printf("%0.1f", data)* to preserve the trailing zeros.

I looked at QString's *arg* function but that only allows the overall field width to be set. *setNum* and *number* each allow the precision to be set but that's not right either.

Example code:

```
double data = 1.0;
label->setText( QString().number( data );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the static function `QString::number()` with format and precision arguments.

```
QString QString::number( double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6 )
```

Reference: http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qstring.html#number-2

Comment: I overlooked changing the format from the default 'g' to 'f' since 'g' includes 'f'.  Missed some words in the description of 'f' as well.

Correct answer:

    double data = 1.0;
    label->setText( QString().number( data, 'f', 1 );

Answer (score 3):

Why not use QString::sprintf() ?

```cpp
QString().sprintf("%08d + rest of the string", 7);
```